# READ File line by line using C

Tags: c

I am working on a program that reads a txt file line by line and copies each line into an empty text file. First the program reads characters until the end of line, and stores all characters read in a buffer. After that it writes the buffer to a text file, and repeats this process until it reaches the end of file. The problem that I'm facing is: the program writes only the first line in the empty file. Can you help to solve this problems please, I'm a newbie in c.

this content  txt file i want to read:

```
hey everyone
how are you
goood
```

and this the output of the programme:
hey everyone

this the Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int GetFileLenght(FILE*FP);

int main()
{
    FILE *SourceFile;
    FILE *DestinationFile;
    int c;
    int i=-1;
    int x=1;
    char buffer[350];
    int lenght;

    lenght=GetFileLenght(SourceFile);
    printf("%d",lenght);
    SourceFile=fopen("D:/SourceFile.txt","r");

    while(i!=lenght)
    {
        c=fgetc(SourceFile);
        printf("%c",c);

        switch(c)
        {
        case '\n' :
            DestinationFile=fopen("d:/des.txt","a+");
            fputs(buffer,DestinationFile);
            *buffer=0;
            fclose(DestinationFile);

            break;

        default:
            i++;
            buffer[i]=c;
            printf("%s",buffer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int GetFileLenght(FILE*FP)
{
    FP = fopen("d:/SourceFile.txt", "a+");
    fseek(FP, 0, SEEK_END);
    int lengthOfFile = ftell(FP);
    fclose(FP);
    return lengthOfFile;
}
```

EDIT:
I have Made some changes to the program ,now it's good:

I'am  also wondering if there is another way to add new line to file using fputs ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main()
{

FILE *SourceFile;
FILE *DestinationFile;
int c=0;
int i=-1;
int x=1;

char buffer[350];



SourceFile=fopen("D:/SourceFile.txt","r");
DestinationFile=fopen("d:/des.txt","a+");

while(x)
{
    c=fgetc(SourceFile);




    switch(c)
    {


    case '\n' :

        fputs(buffer,DestinationFile);
        fprintf(DestinationFile,"\n");
        printf("%s",buffer);
        strncpy(buffer, "", sizeof(buffer));

        i=-1 ;


        break;

    case  EOF :
        fputs(buffer,DestinationFile);
        x=0;

    default:
        i++;
        buffer[i]=c;

    }
}

fclose(DestinationFile);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bad indentation, can't read easily.  Please fix.

Comment: `i++; buffer[i]=c;` You don't reset `i` after each line yet your write code always writes from the start of the bufer `fputs(buffer,DestinationFile);`.

Comment: thanks  kaylum, i didn't really pay attention to that my program now works very well after the changes that i have made